# The contents of a cloud function get request to firestore keep returning undefined

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get access to the contents of a firestore document but i keep getting undefined. I suspect i'm referencing the document wrongly. 
The variable updateId prints to the console correctly and is the value of a firebase auth id which represents a part of the path in firestore db ie users/fireauth_id.

In the document users/fireauth_id i have a field called token i'm trying to return but doc.data.token is always undefined. I did try using the path with .doc({updateId}) instead of doc(updateId) but no luck.

```
 exports.updateRequest = functions.firestore
      .document('users/{userId}')
      .onUpdate(event => {

        var newValue = event.data.data();
        var updateId = newValue.update_id;

        return db.collection('users').doc(updateId).get().then(doc => {

              console.log("this doesn't work: %s", doc.data.token)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "doc.data.token" should be "doc.data().token"

If that's not the case, then I don't think the document you're trying to retrieve exists.